# Is there a jQuery plugin with functionality of CSS3 flexible box model?

Tags: jquery-plugins, css

I want an element organization in my UI equivalent to the results of following CSS:

```css
#wall {
    width: 100%;
    display: box;
    box-orient: horizontal;
    box-align: stretch;
    box-lines: multiple;
}
```

Unfortunately browsers do not seem to support `box-lines: multiple;`, and some widely used browsers do not yet support flexible box model at all.

Is there an existing jQuery plugin that provides this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You asked about this a while ago, but in case you have not looked into this lately, this is a great tool to provide support for the Flexible Box Model in browser that don't support it yet.

[Cross-browser support for the Flexible Box Model](http://flexiejs.com/)

Comment: This is good, but `box-lines: multiple` does not seem to be supported, and the lines feature is actually the most important one for me.